# Microsoft Owin OAuth 1.0

Tags: asp.net, oauth, bitbucket, oauth-1.0a

All the examples included in the Microsoft.Owin.Security.* packages are for OAuth 2.0. I am trying to build a provider for OAuth 1.0, specifically, for BitBucket.

Can anyone provide me with pointers, examples, implementations, or even tell me if it's possible to do this with Microsoft's library with acceptable effort?